# calculate 15th business day ( exclude weekends.) of the next month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the 15th day of the next month after excluding weekends.

for example
if the start date is 7/11/2020, then 15th of the next month will be 8/15/2022 which is saturday, so in this case i need to calculate the 15th day  as 8/17/2020 which is monday.

how i can achieve this . thank you so much for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, you seem to have contradictory requirements for if the 15th falls on a Saturday. You say it should be the next Monday, but then you say the calculated date should be 8/14/2020 (which is the previous Friday, not the following Monday).

Comment: You might want to consider creating and populating a calendar table instead. You can populate it with 20 years worth of data and it's still tiny (less than 10000 rows), and then you can *query* rather than calculate. It also means you can account for public holidays, company events, etc.

Comment: Just weekends? What about holidays? What about days that should have been workdays but were not for some reason (like a natural disaster)? But this is a common question and has many solutions if you just **search**

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have created a Calendar table, it's something like this

```
select 
   FullDateAlternateKey, 
   EnglishDayNameOfWeek, 
   case when DayNumberOfWeek in (7,1) then null
   else sum(case when DayNumberOfWeek not in (7,1) then 1 else 0 end) 
        over (partition by CalendarYear, MonthNumberOfYear order by DateKey) 
   end BusinessDayNumber
from DimDate
order by datekey
```